# Plugging linear operators into polynomials and their factors.

Tags: linear-algebra

Plugging operators into polynomials has always been pretty tricky for me.
Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb F$ and let $D(x)=(x-a_1)^{m_1}(x-a_2)^{m_2} \dots (x-a_k)^{m_k}$. If it is given that $D(T)=0$, what can we say about $ker(T-a_1id), \dots, ker(T-a_kid)$?
And what about $ker(T-a_1id)^{m_1}, \dots, ker(T-a_kid)^{m_k}$?

Since it's hard for me to jump from plugging scalars into polynomials to plugging operators, I immediately think it means $T=a_1id$ or $T=a_2id$ or $\dots$ or $T=a_kid$ but that is not true I think.
Can we determine then anything else about the kernels of $T-a_iid$? About their dimensions? or anything else?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$V=ker(T-a_1id)^{m_1} \oplus \dots \oplus ker(T-a_kid)^{m_k}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the ambiguous question. Could you elaborate why that's true?